# Traefik cannot forward request to httpd service: connection refused

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, devops, lets-encrypt, traefik

I successfully set up Traefik on my personal server. I'm running several containers for which this setup is working perfectly.

However, for one of my containers I get an 502 bad gateway error. This container is an instance of a custom httpd image. The container seems to be working correctly as I can access it directly using the IP address (and port) of the server.

Accessing it from the domain name however, I get an 502 error. This is the error in the Traefik console:

```
traefik_1  | time="2017-10-15T10:12:54Z" level=debug msg="Look for provided certificate to validate [www.mydomain.xyz]..." 
traefik_1  | time="2017-10-15T10:12:54Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains [www.mydomain.xyz], get ACME certificate." 
traefik_1  | time="2017-10-15T10:12:54Z" level=debug msg="Challenge GetCertificate www.mydomain.xyz" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-10-15T10:12:54Z" level=debug msg="ACME got domain cert www.mydomain.xyz" 
traefik_1  | time="2017-10-15T10:12:54Z" level=warning msg="Error forwarding to http://172.18.0.3:6050, err: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6050: getsockopt: connection refused"
```

Below the docker-compose file of my container:

```
version: '2'
services:
  httpd:
    image: mydomain.azurecr.io/httpd:1
    ports:
      - "6050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - traefik_matterhorn
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=mydomain"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_matterhorn"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.mydomain.xyz"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=6050"

networks:
  traefik_matterhorn:
    external: true
```

This is the docker-compose file of my Traefik container:

```
version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.4-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 4080:4080
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - traefik_matterhorn
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml

networks:
  traefik_matterhorn:
    external: true
```

And here my traefik.toml file

```
debug = false
checkNewVersion = true
logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[web]
# Port for the status page
address = ":4080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[acme]
email = "me@mydomain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
```

I'm running Traefik v1.4.0-rc5 / roquefort

Anyone knows what causes this `Error forwarding to http://172.18.0.3:6050, err: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:6050: getsockopt: connection refused` error?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same problem.